# BGE: Orbit script seems to work, but motion is not applied

Tags: game-engine

I want to orbit the camera using a script without centering the cursor. So I wrote this script:

```
import bge

# get this controller script
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
# get sensor named MouseLook
mouse = cont.sensors['MouseLook']
mousePosX = mouse.position[0]
mousePosY = mouse.position[1]
# get old mouse coords
obj = cont.owner
if not 'mousePosOldX' in obj:
    obj['mousePosOldX'] = 0
    obj['mousePosOldY'] = 0

# velocity
velX = mousePosX-obj['mousePosOldX']
velY = mousePosY-obj['mousePosOldY']
# get the actuators
moveH = cont.actuators['MoveH']
moveV = cont.actuators['MoveV']
# apply movement
moveH.dRot = [0, 0, velX*10]
moveV.dRot = [velY*10, 0, 0]
print('velX: {0}, velY: {1}' .format(velX, velY))

# save old pos in obj properties
obj['mousePosOldX'] = mousePosX
obj['mousePosOldY'] = mousePosY
```

Using this setup:

```
-OrbitH
    -OrbitV
        +Camera
```

And this game logic:

[image]

Unfortunately, nothing moves! The script seems to work, because I get valid values in the console from the print.
When I directly connect the Sensor to the actuator without the script, the movement is applied (of course just with these constant values, which I don't want).
So script alone works, and the movement along works too, where is the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found it. Apparently, one have to add:

```
cont.activate(moveH)
cont.activate(moveV)
```

to actually apply the motion

Comment: Please accept your own answer..